# Workaround for Textbox char limit

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

is there a way to disable the textbox char limit or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the textbox increasing in size as well, or is it scrollable? If it's increasing, then you'll have a problem when it gets to 2048 x 2048, at which point it will be clipped. You could simply have textboxes below each other (e.g. in a StackPanel) and when the limit is reached, shift focus to the next textbox.
Also, what limit are you experiencing? I'm under the impression that the default ([MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) = 0) is unlimited characters? (realistically, limited by memory).

Comment: Actually I'm trying to load a bunch of text on textbox. But in some point it reach the maxlimit to display in the UI. The UI has been cut and not visible at all but still scrollable. Im using textboxd inside scrollviewer. And after I load the text, I can edit it as well, that's why I put it on a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) about workaround this issue. In general you have to split text accross multiple TextBoxes and put them in StackPanel.